# Excel formula to find 1st, 2nd, 3rd, minimum occurrence of person entering building based on several criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to build a Table in excel that will give an overview of people's check in/check out time of a building, they are checking in and out multiple times a day and that's fine but the problem I'm having is that there are 3 doors people can enter in and out of, as well as other doors that are in the data-set but which I don't want the info from them.
Basically I am looking for the 1st entry time that is either the front, back or side gate for a particular person on a particular date that is "Access Granted", and then I can replicate that in the cell next to it for the same scenario but "Exit Granted", that should give me the first entrance and exit times with the SMALL function and then for the 2nd entry and exit times I can use SMALL, 2 (second smallest value)
The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to work out the "Front OR Back OR Side" gate part, I have to select only one, my two attempts are below using different methods but they don't seem to be working still, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thankyou

Method 1 - MINIFS Method
=SMALL(MINIFS($D$2:$D$18,$A$2:$A$18,$I4,$B$2:$B$18,$G$4:$G$6, $C$2:$C$18,$O$1,$E$2:$E$18,$H$4),1)

Method 2 - IF(OR)
=SMALL(IF(($A:$A=$I4)*($C:$C=$O$1)*($E:$E=$H$4)*OR($B:$B=$G$4, $B:$B=$G$5, $B:$B=$G$6),$D:$D),1)

[image: Table]

Here is the data in text form:

| Name     | Type              | Date       | Time     | Event          |
|----------|-------------------|------------|----------|----------------|
| Person 1 | Front Gate        | 14/07/2020 | 18:51:19 | Access Granted |
| Person 1 | Side Gate         | 14/07/2020 | 18:57:58 | Exit Granted   |
| Person 1 | Back Gate         | 14/07/2020 | 22:03:48 | Access Granted |
| Person 1 | CMT Turnstile LHS | 14/07/2020 | 22:53:20 | Exit Granted   |
| Person 1 | CMT Turnstile RHS | 14/07/2020 | 23:58:20 | Access Granted |
| Person 1 | Front Gate        | 14/07/2020 | 22:52:20 | Exit Granted   |
| Person 1 | Back Gate         | 15/07/2020 | 01:28:31 | Access Granted |
| Person 2 | Front Gate        | 14/07/2020 | 18:50:30 | Access Granted |
| Person 2 | Side Gate         | 14/07/2020 | 18:57:58 | Exit Granted   |
| Person 2 | Back Gate         | 14/07/2020 | 22:03:48 | Access Granted |
| Person 2 | Front Gate        | 14/07/2020 | 22:52:20 | Exit Granted   |
| Person 2 | Back Gate         | 15/07/2020 | 01:28:31 | Access Granted |
| Person 2 | Front Gate        | 14/07/2020 | 18:51:19 | Access Granted |
| Person 2 | Side Gate         | 14/07/2020 | 18:57:58 | Exit Granted   |
| Person 3 | Back Gate         | 14/07/2020 | 22:03:48 | Access Granted |
| Person 3 | Front Gate        | 14/07/2020 | 22:52:20 | Exit Granted   |
| Person 3 | Back Gate         | 15/07/2020 | 01:28:31 | Access Granted |

Comment: Do you really just want 1st 2nd and 3rd visits or do you want a sum of time on site?  surely 3 visits is an arbitrary restriction?

Comment: No absolutely, I want the sum of all their visits, the way I was doing it was separating it out into 1st visit in and out, 2nd visit in and out, 3rd visit in and out etc and then summing them together, I found that by summing the first time they were in and last time they were out in a day was in-accurate if they were in and out all day!

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Sure would make things a lot simpler if you posted your data as text. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: I have Excel 2016, and sorry about the data, I'm new to this haha, I'll paste it below

Comment: you need to be really careful with the data ,  having worked with access control data before it's rarely safe to assume that you will always get perfectly matching pairs of entries and exits.  E.g. it's quite possible someone will enter 2 times in a row without exiting in between, and vice versa, if they find a secret way out, or tailgate someone else through a door etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different approach,

1. add an 'entry gate' column which is true if gate type matches one of your 3 entry gate types
2. a column for entry time, which is populated with the time if the record is a valid entry record for an entry gate.
3. add a 'Time since Previous Entry' column; populate it for all rows that are valid exit entries, by finding the previous valid entry where EntryGate = true.  Then you just sum that 'Time since previous entry' column to get your time on site.  This extends to an infinite number of entries and exits, whereas your current approach is limited to 3 (or n where n is however many times you copy/paste your formula)

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need to do! I havn't had a chance to retry it again but I'm doing it now, I'll update you if it works, thanks so much for the idea!